# use URL file name instead of index.js with Bower

Tags: javascript, bower

Using Bower, I can download an external URL resource and install it:

`# bower install ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js --save`

But this now maps too an `index.js` file:

```
"jquery": {
  "source": {
    "main": "vendor/jquery/index.js",
  }
}
```

I want the name of the file to be the the same as in the URL if bower metadata is not available:

```
"jquery": {
  "source": {
    "main": "vendor/jquery/jquery.js",
  }
}
```

Possible?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? the issue on github never seemed to be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. Can you [open a ticket](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/new)?